# Render one component over another at a certain route with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a stack navigator with react router, using `@react-navigation/native-stack`.  My home screen is a map, and I have a few menu components:

```js
export const App = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
            component={Home}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignIn"
            component={SignIn}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

`Home` is the map component, and `SignIn`, as well as some other components, are menu components that take over the screen when navigated to, pushing `Home` out of the way, as expected.

I want to be able to 'navigate' to another component at a certain route, call it `Overlay`.  When routed here, I want to show the home screen, with an `Overlay` component laid over the top of part of the `Home` component, while still maintaining interactivity with the part of the Home screen that is not covered.  However, if I do this:

```js
       <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
            component={Home}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Overlay"
            component={Overlay}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

Then the `Home` screen moves away, and is replaced by `Overlay`.

How can I show a component overlaid over the top of my `Home` screen when the user is routed to a certain route?  This is something easily done with react-router, but I'm not sure if there is a parallel in react-navigation.  Is react-navigation not the right approach for this?  Is it better to conditionally render the `Overlay` component based on a state/redux variable?

Comment: Have you examine React Navigation screen as modal navigation behavior - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/

Comment: @ShyPenguin I should have been more specific in my question.  I just edited it.  I want the overlay component to ony partially obscure the Home screen, and still allow interactivity with the part of the home screen that is not obscured.  The navigation modal docs specify that 'a modal displays content that temporarily blocks interactions with the main view.'

Comment: I don"t know if this UI Design pattern is specific to your app but React Navigation follows a common design pattern from Google Material Design and Apple Human Interface Guidelines. Check also bottom sheet  - https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet